# .net core 5 signalr cors blocked with wildcard

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, signalr

Why dont work allow **all** cors  ?

**.net core 5 web api:**

```
   services.AddCors();
   services.AddSignalR();


   app.UseCors(c => c.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
```

**js file:**

```
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr'

let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("https://localhost:5001/ws/candlehub")
    .build();

connection.start()
    .then(() => connection.invoke("ConnectToCandle", "x"));
```

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing

By default the javascript client uses `withCredentials = true` which does not work with `*` origins as per the CORS spec. You should either, specify the explicit origins you want to allow and include `AllowCredentials()` on your CORS config, or set `withCredentials = false` on the `HubConnectionBuilder` options.