# Cross-domain SignalR importing issue

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

Is it even possible to use cross-domain SignalR with vanilla js on the client side?
It seems kinda impossible to me, because I think I've tried everything to set it up right.
Server side is .NET Core Web App and the Client side is just html, css and vanilla js.
If I import the SignalR in my scripts.js file like this:

```
import HubConnectionBuilder from "@microsoft/signalr"
```

I  get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@microsoft/signalr". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Then, I tried to copy the signalr.js file in the folder and import it directly:

```
import HubConnectionBuilder from "./signalr"
```

I am getting this

```
GET http://10.50.28.251:8080/FrontEnd/static/signalr net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Then if I add .js at the end of it:

```
import HubConnectionBuilder from "./signalr.js"
```

I get this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './signalr.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Finally I try this:

```
import * as signalR from  "./signalr.js"

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44368/chatHub").build();
```

Still, not helping:

```
Uncaught TypeError: signalR.HubConnectionBuilder is not a constructor
```

Scripts.js file:

```
import * as jQuery from "../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
jQuery
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from  "../../node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"

var connection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44368/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What does `signalr.js` look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.net core 5 signalr cors blocked with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853705/net-core-5-signalr-cors-blocked-with-wildcard)

Comment: Can't  edit my question for some reason to add scripts.js file
Basically it is the same as in the 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0
Except I just wanted to make it cross-domain.

Comment: this isn't a cross domain issue. If you are using one server then it definitely isn't cross domain.

Comment: Post source directory structure please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The js file isn't found that means the server isn't serving those files. If you are using a folder other than wwwroot then you then to specify this in the asp core server.

To customize what static files are served you need to modify the `app.UseStaticFiles()`.  The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) here have more details on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Signalr has depend of jquery hence before import you can use following lines

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
```

Comment: After installing jquery through npm and adding these 2 lines of code now my http-server can't find the index.html for some reason.